# My Python script quits after about 5 minutes from startup of RPI

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I wrote a small python script that checks to see if something is connected to a specific IP address from my raspberry pi then changed the value of one of 3 GPIO pins to turn on LEDS for connected, not connected, or errors in connecting. The code runs on boot of the rpi and works perfectly for the first 4.5-5min then just gets stuck at whatever point in the code it was at.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# /etc/init.d/ping.py
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:     ping.py
# Required-Start:   $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:     0 1 6
# Short-Description:    Start daemon at boot time
# Descripton:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

import subprocess
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# Set up pins, address, GPIO
address = '10.101.60.131'
grn = 8
red = 10
yel = 12
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(grn, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(red, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(yel, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(grn, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(red, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(yel, GPIO.LOW)

last = 5
# main loop, checks if network is there
while(1):
    ret = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '3', address])
    if (ret != last):
        # network responded correctly
        if ret == 0:
            print('ping to ' + address + ' OK')
            GPIO.output(grn, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(red, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(yel, GPIO.LOW)
            last = 0
        # network was not located
        elif ret == 2:
            print('no response from ', address)
            GPIO.output(grn, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(red, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(yel, GPIO.LOW)
            last = 2
        # other error in setup
        else:
            print('ping to ', address, ' failed')
            GPIO.output(grn, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(red, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(yel, GPIO.HIGH)
            last = 3
```

If i run the code outside of the boot (start it in the python IDLE) it runs fine. Let me know if theres more information needed.

Comment: Are you startIng this from `systemd`? I think scripts are normally supposed to start other things **in the background** and then exit within 90 seconds or so.

Comment: I used method 3 from this site https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/ which involves setting the script to run through the init.d file in the boot partition

Comment: I think you have beem misled by that article. Look at `service.sh` on this page https://gist.github.com/naholyr/4275302 You should respond to parameters `start` and `stop` and `restart` and you should only do relatively short-lived things like starting your Python script in the background then exiting.

Comment: So basically i can run something short lived. Would the workaround be to use the script to start my python program then?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Store your script somewhere else and do `python /some/place/else/YourScript.py &`

Comment: Awesome thanks Mark!

Comment: When you get it working, post it here as an answer with brief explanation for other folks to see. Then accept your own answer as correct and bag the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I managed to fix this was to run the python code from `/etc/profile`. In /etc/profile at the end of the file I added `sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/filenamehere.py &` and then saved and rebooted.